# Using different libraries in clusterCall and doParallel

Tags: r, loops, dplyr, foreach, doparallel

I am trying to use foreach and dopar for my loops. I will try to be brief.
My code looks like:

```
cl = makeCluster (10)
registerDoParallel(cl)
clusterCall(cl,function()library(dplyr))
```

But now i created a function which uses functions from lubridate(year and month functions) and dplyr(pipe to be precise from magrittr) both.
What should be the correct approach here? Thanks in advance.

Previously the pipe operator showed the same problem until i used the magrittr or dplyr but i just don't know how to apply the same for two different libraries.

Comment: Try `function()library(c("dplyr", "lubridate"))`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas. Sir i tried it previously but it shows the error ,"package must be of length 1".

Comment: I am not getting any error in this code.

Comment: @Eva it doesn't work for me.  I used clustercall(cl,function()c(library(dplyr), library (lubridate))). This worked for the loop.Thank you all

Comment: Instead of `c()` use curly braces, `clusterCall(cl,function(){library(dplyr);library(lubridate)})`. It's probably better.